# Как очистить память, выделенную для переменной?

Tags: c++, память

Как очистить память, выделенную для переменной в C++?
Есть переменная, которую я больше не буду использовать; как удалить эту переменную, очистив память, которую она занимала?

Comment: Почитайте всётаки про `malloc` - `free` и `new` - `delete`

Comment: @nick_n_a, мне почему-то кажется, что там ни `malloc`, ни `new` не было даже :)

Comment: о**Т**чистить память можно с помощью `memset` :)

Comment: а вот "почистить memset'ом" не всегда получается. Если после этого память не используется (а она не должна использоваться - мы же делаем зачистку финальную),  то компилятор может выбросить memset.

Comment: @KoVadim в таких случаях надо использовать что-то вроде `SecureZeroMemory`.

Comment: конечно. Но только в Вашем комментарии этого не было.

Comment: @KoVadim я не могу предвосхищать все нюансы в одном сообщении. Более того в комментарии, и ещё более - на довольно сомнительный вопрос ТС.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы о статической или динамической?

Если это что-то типа переменной, объявленной в духе `string s;` - то объявите ее так, чтобы она выходила из области видимости, когда больше не нужна - при выходе будет вызван деструктор, который освободит *связанные с переменной* ресурсы - типа выделенной ей динамической памяти. Еще раз - освободятся выделенные ресурсы, но не память, выделенная статически под саму переменную.

Если это переменные фундаментальных типов наподобие `int i`, `double d` - то не заморачивайтесь: они все равно выделены в стеке (или соответствующем сегменте памяти, если это глобальные переменные или статические переменные функций). Достаточно умный компилятор и так разберется, что с ними делать.

Ну, а с динамическими типа `int * p = new int[20000];` - так руками освобождайте память: `delete[]p;`. Или пользуйтесь интеллектуальными указателями и советом выше.

Comment: А не "умный" компилятор разве не разберётся с автоматическими переменными?

Comment: @alexolut Я имею в виду, что если в функции идет использование переменной `i`, скажем, в первой половине как счетчика цикла, и больше она не используется, а во второй половине - переменная `j`, и их области *использования* не пересекаются, то компилятор может использовать для них одну область памяти. Такая оптимизация вполне возможна, кажется, даже в "Книге Дракона - 2" обсуждается. Не очень умный компилятор не станет этим заморачиваться.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас есть два основных вида переменных и, как следствие, два способа.

Первое. Явное выделение памяти с помощью `new` или `new[]` (да, можно и malloc, но это уже как бы си). Такая память освобождается вызовом `delete` или `delete[]` (или free, если захотелось использовать malloc и его аналоги). В современном мире это дело давно автоматизировали используют умные указатели - `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` и другие.

пример.

```
 Foo * f = new Foo; // создали
 delete f; // освободили
```

Второе. Это локальные переменные (они же автоматические). Они живут до конца блока и компилятор сам вставляет код для их освобождения.

```
{
  Foo f;
  // используем f
  //..
  // здесь неявно компилятор сам вставит удаление для f
}
```

управлять временем жизни можно, если правильно размещать переменные внутри блока и вовремя его закрывать.

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно, и не должно вам хотеться.

Памятью, выделяемой под переменные, заведует компилятор сам, и он, если видит, что переменная вами больше не используется, может использовать её память под другие переменные. Или он может вообще не выделять память для переменной, а поместить её в регистр процессора. Или он может при оптимизации вообще выкинуть вашу переменную.

Поверьте, компилятор делает это намного лучше нас с вами.

Comment: В вопросе на самом деле не указано какие это переменные: автоматические или динамические.

Comment: @alexolut: А что есть динамическая переменная?

Comment: Я имею в виду *automatic storage duration* и *dynamic storage duration*. Но не стоит забывать ещё и про *static* и *thread*.

Comment: @alexolut: Но это ж наверное не называется «переменной»?

Comment: Допустим, есть запись `T* p = new T;` Что нас здесь больше интересует: жизнь указателя `p` или жизнь данных, на которые он указывает? Переменная `p` уничтожится при выходе из блока, а вот данные, на которые она указывает лишь при вызове `delete p;`.

Comment: @alexolut: Ну мало ли что нас интересует? Если, к примеру, `p` есть голова односвязного списка, то нас интересует удаление всего списка. Но вы ведь не называем удаление списка очисткой переменной?

Comment: Учитывая исходную постановку вопроса предполагать можно всё что угодно. Меня вообще несколько удивило как на такой неясный вопрос посыпались множественные ответы.

Comment: @alexolut: Простой вопрос, low hanging fruit :-)