# Область видимости и удаление переменной

Tags: c++, область-видимости

Имеет ли смысл заключить следующее в фигурные скобки, чтобы переменная "run" была удалена?

```
    {
bool run = true;
while (run)
    run = false; 
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, можете спросить более развернуто? Заключить в фигурные скобки что? Тело цикла `while` или весь этот код (который и так в скобках)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну... спрашивается, имеет ли смысл заключать использование переменной `run` в отдельную область видимости, как в приведённом примере. Думаю, вопрос на тему области видимости, времени жизни, памяти и всякое такое.

Comment: Как минимум для читабельности данного куска кода, стоит.

Comment: Думаю, что для такого фундаментального типа, для которого не нужен деструктор по окончанию времени жизни, разберется оптимизатор и позволит занять ее место (при необходимости) другой переменной. Словом, чисто для "удалить переменную фундаментального типа", мне кажется, особого смысла не имеет - разве что имя надо вывести из области видимости, чтоб не скрывало что другое. Для сложных типов, например, чтоб файловый поток закрыл файл - дело другое...

Comment: @Harry, для сложных типов, которые держат ресурсы, если нужно освободить ресурсы посредине метода (то что-то пошло не так) , кажется, читабельней явно вызывать метод, который эти ресурсы освобождает, чем заключать в лишние {}.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Далеко не всегда. По мне куда логичнее, например, завершить работу с каким-то `ofstream` выходом имени за пределы области видимости, чем вызвать `close()` и остаться с по сути дохлой переменной. Только затеняет смысл - что все, работа с этой переменной закончена...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать это имеет смысл, только если планируется использовать имя `run` далее в коде в другом значении. В других случаях, т.к. тип фундаментальный и память выделена не динамически, компилятор сам позаботится о памяти, выделенной под него.

На этом сайте уже был [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/659123/344284), в ответах на который всё довольно понятно разъяснено.